# Is there a way to manage modules deployed on iotedge device by using AKS(Azure Kubernetes Service)?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-iot-edge

I have been looking at using the kubernetes for container orchestration . However, as far as i know kubernetes could be on-prem or managed as service through Azure Kubernetes Service. I have known that on-prem support for K8s is being provided by edge , however I wonder how this would work if my workloads were on AKS.

Comment: Make sure to capture the question/description clearly, so that people who are willing to answer can answer your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify your scenario more?

We have a public preview that one can register a k8s cluster as an edge device. And can deploy applications to the k8s cluster Edge through iothub. The k8s cluster can be on-prem or aks. Same instructions can be followed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-kubernetes.

Another way is to connect iothub to a K8s cluster through virtual kublet. https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-virtual-kubelet-provider. 
This way your workload can be deployed to Edge devices by iothub with k8s api or kubectl.

Would like to understand the needs and hear feedback when trying.

Thanks 
Cindy Xing @msft

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was interested in understanding how would aks fit with iot edge deployment, as I would prefer my k8s cluster to be cloud-managed. It would be useful for me to know if there is any documentation detailing how AKS works with IOT -Edge .

Comment: I see. If you try the instruction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-kubernetes), the iotedge runtime will be deployed to your aks cluster. One can then deploy IOT modules to the aks cluster through iothub. The AKS cluster can still be cloud-managed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly your question, but I understood that you would like to manage IoT edge deployments through K8s. Is my understanding correct?

[There](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/manage-azure-iot-edge-deployments-with-kubernetes/) is an experimental project that helps managing IoT Edge deployments via simple kubectl commands